# I can call 34 random words from Chainlink VRF but not 35 or more. Why?

Tags: solidity, gas, hardhat, chainlink, randomness

I am trying to call my `requestRandomness` function in my main contract that calls a VRFCoordinatorV2Mock contract in my local hardhat environment.

According to my unit tests I am able to emit a `ReceivedRandomWords` event in my `fulfillRandomWords` function; thus confirming I have received the randomness back from the Chainlink network. However, as soon as I change my `NUM_WORDS` to 35 or more, I get an error message in hardhat and the event stops being emitted.

I have tried changing my `callbackGasLimit` and I still cannot get it to work. Can someone help me please?

**UPDATE:**

So I have learned that by simply running `yarn hardhat test` the test passes but when I do `yarn hardhat test --network localhost` it fails and gives me the original error...

Comment: It may depend on what you're doing with the numbers and whether it is out of gas. Hard to say just with the information provided.

Comment: In order to to help you, could you share the error here?